# Google Docs - Scripts, copy cell from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I need to copy a cell from a sheet to corresponding cell in another sheet

From here: 
[image: Screenshot of a google doc]

to here: 
[image: Screenshot of a second google dog]

[My sheet can be viewed here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As27d35fUMfcdDY1TGhzRHNOaU9PLWo5ald3STdTdFE&usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if you can access multiple sheets with google docs scripts, but I may be wrong

Comment: I think that's possible, I'm looking at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494175/google-script-select-and-copy-some-values-from-spreadsheet-comparing-to-another

Answer (score 2):

Please report back if this is not achieving what you require.

```
function updateVerified() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Calculates!D5:K').getValues();
  var respSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
  var respTs = respSheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
  var respRange = respSheet.getRange('F2:F');
  var respValues = respRange.getValues();
  var convTs = [], temp;

  for (var i = 0; i < respTs.length; i++) {
    convTs[i] = respTs[i][0] ? respTs[i][0].getTime() : '';
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < source.length; j++) {
    if (!source[j][0]) break;
    temp = convTs.indexOf(source[j][0].getTime());
    if (temp > -1) respValues[temp][0] = source[j][7];
  }

  respRange.setValues(respValues);
}
```