# How do I copy data from one cell to another based on a cell value? (Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to copy data from a sheet (SheetA) to another sheet (SheetB)
However, I need the row of the cell to be copied (From Sheet A) to be based off of another cell.

For example:
SheetA has data on A1, A2, A3, A4 etc...
SheetB has a cell (B1) that a user types in a value.
When the script is run the data from SheetA will be copied from column A and a row based off of the value in B1 to SheetB.
So if a user types "5" into B1 and runs, the data from A5 will be copied from SheetA to A1 on sheetB

Here is a script that I have so far, how do I modify this correctly to complete the code?

```
    //Moves data from SheetA -> SheetB;
   SheetA.getRange("?").copyTo(SheetB.getRange("A1"));
```

What do I have to replace where the '("?")' is?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a similar question on SO. Please see, [Copy values and formatting to...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494175/google-script-select-and-copy-some-values-from-spreadsheet-comparing-to-another?rq=1]) Please see and let us know where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Using setValue() instead will be easier to implement and understand.

Try to implement like below:

> Get the value of the input from SheetB

```
var inputValue = SheetB.getRange(SheetBRow, SheetBColumn).getValue();
```

-

> Use the inputValue as a row parameter for getRange() to get the value
>   of a cell from SheetA

```
var SheetACellValue = SheetA.getRange(inputValue, SheetAColumn).getValue();
```

-

> Set the value of a cell on SheetB using the value from SheetACellValue

```
Cell SheetBCell = SheetB.getRange(SheetBRow,SheetBColumn);
SheetBCell.setValue(SheetACellValue);
```

You can implement this by method chaining. I just divided each for a better view and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you defined SheetA and SheetB and the copyTo Range is fixed (A1) this is your code (following the syntax in your attempt):

```
SheetA.getRange('A'+SheetB.getRange('B1').getValue).copyTo(SheetB.getRange('A1'));
```

or (using setValue instead of copyTo because you are adressing one specific cell):

```
SheetB.getRange('B1').setValue(SheetA.getRange('A'+SheetB.getRange('B1').getValue));
```

This is basic knowledge when working with Apps Script and Sheets. I recommend you read up on the [SpreadsheetApp Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).
Moreover this is a duplicate of so many similar questions. Next time search for your question using the `google-apps-script` tag.