# Conditionally copy Rows from one sheet to another (again!)

Tags: google-apps-script

Another poster already provided a great answer to another question about "Google Script: Conditionally copy rows from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet".

[Their answer is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665698/google-script-conditionally-copy-rows-from-one-sheet-to-another-in-the-same-spr)

**MY QUESTION:** I have a difficult time porting their answer into my problem.  Can someone point me to a place where I know how to read their script, and adjust it accordingly with my particular google sheet.  Is there a good basic answer on transposing scripts for beginners?  I am a total neophyte around programming language.

For what it is worth, I believe it should transfer well to my document, which I have editable and linked [HERE!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/111w7Q5LjtWNa7uHz-Okd9G7nku-G2MRr_hbQvXwM2NI/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like to take rows from my MASTER sheet, and when I have an X (or any marker in the column under "Volunteer" to have it move to the VOLUNTEER sheet.

I know this is elementary, but I would love insight.

Answer (score 2):

```
function copyFromMasterToVolunteer()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht1=ss.getSheetByName('MASTER');
  var sht2=ss.getSheetByName('ACTIVE Volunteers');
  var rng1=sht1.getDataRange();
  var rng1A=rng1.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<rng1A.length;i++)
  {
    if(rng1A[i][14]!='')
    {
      sht2.appendRow(rng1A[i]);
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```