# Google Spreadsheet - copy of mastersheet for editing and append new data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would be grateful for your help. I am not sure if this question has been asked before, if so I apologize. I use Google spreadsheet responses linked to a Google Form.  This spreadsheet collects responses from the form. I need to leave this intact – ie. users should not be editing this spreadsheet. So I would need to pull the data from it into another spreadsheet. I know I could do this easily with importrange. However, the problem is that users cannot edit it. Basically I would need to pull data from the original spreadsheet to another spreadsheet, so that users can edit it – but this editable sheet should also be able to pull additional data from the original spreadsheet when it gets updated with new responses. Would that be possible at all? I tried to look for a suitable google apps script, but could not find it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Form has separate sharing permissions from the Spreadsheet it is linked to. So, you could restrict the Form to only be accessible/editable by you and give edit permissions to the linked Spreadsheet to others.

Those in the Spreadsheet will see the Form menu. If they attempt to use the function under the menu they will get prompted to Request Access from the owner of the Form. One notable exception is the `Unlink form`, since they have edit permissions of the Spreadsheet they are allowed to unlink the form. So if anyone unlinks the form you will need to relink it. Another possible approach is to setup some script on the form that relinks the spreadsheet by some trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately this would not work in this work environment for a number of reasons. The only workable solution I can see is having a copy of the mastersheet which would be editable and be updated with new data automatically. There was a script called "edit to another spreadsheet" which seems to do what I need but this is not working at all - and it is also rather old. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Actually there is another post here which seems to do what I want (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590132/collect-data-from-several-spreadsheets-and-copy-it-into-another-sheet), but I am having some difficulty because on the master spreadsheet I have columns say from A to AH, but I just need to copy additional row data from columns to A to G for example when the master spreadsheet gets new submission updates. Hope someone can help me with this. Many thanks.