# How to cut & paste rows from Google spread sheet to another after x-times repeatly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, repeat

Please help me with this problem.

I have a big data in a Google spread sheet. I just want to cut & paste just 10 rows to another Google spread sheet. I want to repeat this tasks every 15 minutes. How to do that?

See demo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ey5OCYKbIFZ-PHEtUPjRoORBiPyHKAsQxq4zKCZ0pgs/edit?usp=sharing

As the link above, I want to cut & paste some rows from sheet 1 to sheet 2, every 15 minutes by automatic.

I will be appreciate by your helps.

Comment: While in my opinion *not* a duplicate, your question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4509336/1586231).  Reading the answers to that may help.  I would guess you could go one of two routes: google scripting, or publish to web as TSV/CSV and write a script to automatically check that address and proceed accordingly.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

## Cut And Paste ten rows every ten minutes

This should do it for you. This will Cut and paste the ten bottom rows of 'Master' sheet to 'Copy' sheet. You have to run myCutAndPaste() the first time and then it creates a ten minute time but it will not create more than one. When it gets the header row it stops and deletes the trigger.  With a small change the two sheets are in different spreadsheets.

```
function myCutAndPaste()
{
  setupTrigger();
  var ss0=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss0.getSheetByName('Master');
  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Your ID');
  var sh1=ss1.getSheetByName('Copy');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg0.getValues();
  var lng=vA.length;
  for(var i=lng-1;i>lng-10;i--)
  {
    if(i<1)
    {
      deleteTrigger('myCutAndPaste');
      break;
    }
    sh1.appendRow(vA[i]);
    sh0.deleteRow(i+1);
    var end='near the end';
  }
}

function setupTrigger()
{
  if(!isTrigger('myCutAndPaste'))
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myCutAndPaste').timeBased().after(600000).create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(handlerName)
{
  var r=false;
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++) 
  {
    if (handlerName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()) 
    {
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function deleteTrigger(handlerName)
{
  var myTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i=0;i<myTriggers.length;i++)
  {
    if(myTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()==handlerName)
    {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(myTriggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thank you for your helps. But I just like automation every 15 minutes because I cannot click run for >1m rows in excel.

Comment: You only have to run it once to get it started.

Comment: hi Cooper, Sorry for my misunderstand. Your idea is good but I like:
- Cut and paste from a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet (every spreadsheet has 1 sheet only).
- Just replace rows in "Copy"" spreadsheet instead of add more rows in the end.
- Change 10 rows to 100 every cut & paste. 
Again, Cooper, thank you for helps.

Comment: Okay now sh0 is from one spreadsheet and sh1 is from another.  One assumption we make here is that you are a person who wants to learn how to program.  There I would suggest that you  plan on making your own adjustments to our suggestions.  The sooner you start to code on your own, the sooner you'll learn Google Apps Script.

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for your suggestion. Please help me to redjust this: cutting 10 rows in Master spreadsheet and replacing them in Copy spreadsheet. Thank you again.
p.s: my staff is learning Google scripts but we are newcommer so I cannot control it. :(