# When updating calendar event with google script how to send notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

From Google Spreadsheet I create events using Google Script. When creating events I can send notifications to guests.

One or more events need to be updated sometimes (change location, add/remove people, etc).

The updates work except I cannot find how to send notification to people (not all guests will be on Google Calendar).

Though I have seen something in the API that might do the trick, I don't know if it is possible/how to encorporate this in the script I wrote.

Please advise.

Update 20180130@10:39:
**Error: Invalid attendee email**

```
function sendInvite(calendarId, eventId, email) {
  var n = eventId.indexOf("@")
  var str = eventId.substring(0,n)
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, str);
  Logger.log(event.attendees);
  if(event.attendees) {
    event.attendees.push({
      email: email
    });
  } else {
    event.attendees = new Array({email: email});
  }
  Logger.log('')
  Logger.log(event.attendees)
  Logger.log('')
  Logger.log(event)

  event = Calendar.Events.patch(event, calendarId, str, {
    sendNotifications: true
  });
}
```

The Log shows after removing identifiables:

```
18-01-30 10:31:27:213 CET] [{responseStatus=needsAction, email=some@something.com}, {responseStatus=needsAction, email=some@something.com}]
[18-01-30 10:31:27:214 CET] 
[18-01-30 10:31:27:215 CET] [{responseStatus=needsAction, email=some@something.com}, {responseStatus=needsAction, email=some@something.com}, {email=some@something.com,some@something.com}]
[18-01-30 10:31:27:215 CET] 
[18-01-30 10:31:27:216 CET] {reminders={useDefault=true}, summary=test 3, creator={displayName=MyName, self=true, email=some@something.com}, kind=calendar#event, htmlLink=https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=************, created=2018-01-30T09:09:15.000Z, attendees=[{responseStatus=needsAction, email=some@something.com}, {responseStatus=needsAction, email=some@something.com}, {email=some@something.com,some@something.com}], iCalUID=***ID***@google.com, start={dateTime=2018-01-31T16:00:00+01:00, timeZone=Europe/Amsterdam}, description=Agenda will be added later, sequence=2, organizer={displayName=MyName, self=true, email=some@something.com}, etag="***etag***", end={dateTime=2018-01-31T17:00:00+01:00, timeZone=Europe/Amsterdam}, location=Thuis, id=***ID***, updated=2018-01-30T09:31:26.758Z, status=confirmed}
```

Comment: See for related issue the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509336/how-to-copy-a-row-from-one-google-spreadsheet-to-another-google-spreadsheet-usin/10485959#10485959