# Copy Specific Data in one Google Spreadsheet to another Google Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that people will fill out and then hit a submit button. That button creates a PDF and emails that data to people. A portion of that data needs to be compiled in another spreadsheet each time someone submits their data.

I have code that can copy a range and paste it in the spreadsheet.

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abcd1234'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Timesheet'); // ss = source sheet
  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getRange("A10:L22");
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abcd1234'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Info'); // ts = target sheet
  var TRange = ts.getRange("A1:L13");
  var T1Range = TRange.getA1Notation();

  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(T1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

I have **two issues** with this code:

1. **I cannot select specific cells of data**, I need to select J6 but also the entire 11th row. A bonus would be if it sees a value in say, A14, then it will copy the whole 14th row. But if nothing is in A14 it will not copy that data.
2. **The data overwrites itself each time data is submitted**, I need each new addition of data to just show up under the last one.

I have been looking for a solution to this for hours and am not versed in Javascript enough to write anything custom. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the script below you can see how you can select individual cells or entire rows and how you can copy their contents into another sheet.

There's also an example of how you can check if a cell has a value or not.

You can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809413/7388888) how you can copy stuff into an existing sheet without overwriting what's already in there.

```js
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
    
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID'); // Selects your Source Spreadsheet by its ID
    var ssheet = sourceSheet.getSheetByName('Timesheet'); // Selects your Source Sheet by its Name
   
    var J6value = ssheet.getRange(6, 10).getValue();  // Get value from J6 in Source Sheet
    var A14value = ssheet.getRange(14, 1).getValue(); // get value from A14 in Source Sheet
    
    var the11thRow = ssheet.getRange('A11:11').getValues(); // Select the entire 11th row in the Source Sheet
    var the14thRow = ssheet.getRange('A14:14').getValues(); // Select the entire 14th row in the Source Sheet
       
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID'); // Selects your Target Spreadsheet by its ID
    var tsheet = targetSheet.getSheetByName('Info'); // Selects your Target Sheet by its name
    
    var targetFor14thRow = tsheet.getRange('A11:11'); // Selects where your 11th row will be copied to, in this case simply row 11
    var targetFor11thRow = tsheet.getRange('A14:14'); // Selects where your 14th row will be copied to, in this case simply row 14
      
    if (!ssheet.getRange(14, 1).isBlank()) { // Conditional: If A14 in Source Sheet isn't empty
      targetFor14thRow.setValues(the14thRow); // Then copy the entire 14th row to its target
    }
          
    tsheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(J6value); // Copy the value of J6 in the source document to 2A of the Target Sheet
    tsheet.getRange(3,4).setValue(A14value); // Copy the value of A12 in the source document to C4 of the Target Sheet    
  }
```

**EDIT:** Use .setValues instead of .copyTo in order to copy entire rows.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful info, I am getting the error "Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet." when I try to run it though.

Comment: Hey there, sorry about that. If you use .setValues(values) it will do the job. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I was able to use some code I found with your 'if' statement and I now have a fully working piece. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TacoSteve Glad to hear that. In this case, I'd be thankful if you could mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I gathered some more code this is working beautifully now.

```
function CopyDataToNewFile(targetSheetName,targetSsId, sourceSheetName,sourceSsId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abcd1234sydfhnsgb').getSheetByName('Timesheet');
  var ssd = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abcd1234srymsnzd').getSheetByName('Info');

  var therapist = ss.getRange('D6:K6').getValues();
  var sourceData10 = ss.getRange('A10:10').getValues();  
  ssd.getRange(ssd.getLastRow()+1,1,therapist.length,therapist[0].length).setValues(therapist);

  if (!ss.getRange(10, 1).isBlank()) {
    ssd.getRange(ssd.getLastRow()+1,1,sourceData10.length,sourceData10[0].length).setValues(sourceData10);
  }
}
```