# How to copy Google pivot table (values and format) to another spreadsheet using appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet(say A) which contains a pivot table in one of the sheets. 
Another sheet contains the source data for that pivot table.
I want to only copy the table from the sheet to another spreadsheet(say B) as I have to send the spreadhsheet B containing the single sheet in email.

I tried the following solutions suggested in the similar issue link below but they don't seem to solve my problem:
[How to copy a row from one google spreadsheet to another google spreadsheet using google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509336/how-to-copy-a-row-from-one-google-spreadsheet-to-another-google-spreadsheet-usin)

1. Copy sheet from spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B. This failed because
   the source data sheet was not in B.
2. Tried `range.copyTo()` but this failed too because it only works if
   applied on the same spreadsheet.
3. Copied values i.e used `getValues()` and `setValues()`. This might work
   but I also want the format to be copied.

Comment: Combine 1 and 3

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? 
in my understanding I cannot do that because when I perform #1 #REF! (Error: Unresolved sheet name <sourceSheetName>) gets displayed instead of the pivot table . Here the sourceSheetName is the name of the sheet which generated the pivot table.

Comment: Copy the sheet (this will copy the formatting, yes?) Then write the values from the original sheet. This will remove the pivot table, and it will be just values.

Comment: I just tried combining 1 an 3. Copying the sheet copied the sheet formatting but the pivot table formatting did not get copied.

Comment: Edit your question with the necessary details (someone with 10+ rep can inline a screenshot showing the desired and reproduced formats)